# Saving Video without the use of intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)

Tags: android, video, video-recording

I am recording the video through the intent and displaying in the Video View, but not saving it in file. I want the user to select whether to save that file or not later on in the activity. Please suggest how to save the video without using  "intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)"

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    caseR.id.vbVid: 
        Toast.makeText(Vid.this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        recordVideo(0);
        break;

    caseR.id.vbSave: 
        //saving the video when user click the button
        break;
    }

}

private void recordVideo() {

        Intent l = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (l.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(l, 0);

        }
}


protected void onActivityResult(intrequestCode, intresultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 &&resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(Vid.this, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri uriv = (Uri) data.getData();
        videoView.setVideoURI(uriv);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what you're doing now, show a "would you like to save" dialog at the end of the video 
and, if user says no - delete your file.

As I'm sure you understand, the video must be stored somewhere to allow later saving by the user.